# RegEx to exclude match if a certain word is present, but not another partial word

Tags: regex, url, filtering, firewall

I have the keyword "cum" which our firewall uses to block adult sites, problem is this works a little too well because this also blocks any URL with the word "document"

The firewall will take regex strings, and I tried this:

```
^.*(?!document)cum.*$
```

Vut it still matches "document". I have a feeling I should be using a pipe `|` but I don't get it.

What I want is to match anywhere

```
*cum*
```

is found in the URL (or domain-name), but NOT if the word is `document` or `documents`.

Possible?  As I understand it, a word boundary doesn't work here because the word `cum` won't necessarily be separated by white-space when it's in a URL, and definitely not if it's in a domain-name.

Here's another way to put it:

```
Allow "examplesearchdocuments.com"
Allow "examplemydocuments.com"
Allow "documentexample.com"
Allow "example.com/somedocuments"
Don't allow "funnycumsiteexample.com"
Don't allow "cumallovereverythingexample.com"
Don't allow "exampleseemycum.com"
```

where `cum` being the bad word match. Sorry if any of these examples are real sites, I don't know how else to convey this.

Comment: Can you use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (i.e., `\b`)? or would that still be too permissive?

Comment: @user1630785 You are going to block URL's that contain s 'cum' as a keyword!This WONT work...It's better if you block URL's by the websites contents not URL

Comment: actually blocking "cum" works great to get rid of 1000's of adult sites, and lowers our firewall's memory usage because we don't have to list each URL or domain where "cum" is present.  My work-around currently is to white-list the specific sites where "document" is in the URL, but I just wanted to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @user1630785 this is bad..there are still many valid websites out there having `cum`..Are you going to block http://www.cumulus.com/ OR cumulus.com.au

Comment: there are almost 130+ words that contain cum..singling out document is senseless

Comment: Agreed, with Internet filtering nothing is ever perfect, it's a losing battle - I like to err on the side of "block first, ask questions later" - I can always white-list the discrepancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, I was wrong.

If you use a lookbehind inside your lookahead, you can match "cum" only if it is not within the word "document".

```
cum(?!(?<=docum)ent)
```

Here is some reading on lookaround http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Here it is against a large number of tests.

http://www.rubular.com/r/b5iZrn6Cjz

Comment: I thank you and and the gentleman below for your insight!  I green checked your response simply because you were first to answer.  This is good enough for my purposes, I can always white-list anything I want.

Comment: What if you put a lookbehind in the lookahead assertion, like so:  `cum(?!(?<=docum)ent)`?

Comment: great stuff.  I love using rubular to answer questions here because it's as smooth for regex as jsfiddle is for javascript  It really helps to be able to play with it.

Comment: Thank you, because my firewall only recognizes a regex statement if it starts with ^ I went with this: ^.*cum(?!(?<=docum)ent) see test case: http://www.rubular.com/r/cUzrBnUxCM

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would also be to use `\bcum\b` as the others, but that doesn't match e.g. cumming.

You're almost right with the negative lookaround `(?!)` syntax:

- For negative lookbehind you need the `<`
- For negative lookahead you need don't need `>`
- See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more

> `^.*(?<!do)cum(?!ent).*$`

or

> `^.*(?<!do)cum(?!ents?).*$`

to support plural.
You can check it at: http://fiddle.re/3pyj by clicking Java for a the examples you provided.

*My suggestion would be `^.*\bcum.*$` to match a word boundary, i.e. word start and the 'cum' and anything after.*

Comment: yours is pretty slick, I like how you're solving the problem of lookarounds, even though it doesn't work :(

Comment: why not? I just tried with his examples at it gives the results he expects. Also yours is the same, except the `.*`s and the "match all input with `^$`" part.

Comment: it fails on docum as if it had found the word document, try documwithus.com or facialbookcument.com

Comment: I like the documwithus.com it could be real :)
But I still don't understand why you're blaming mine, if yours fails on that too.

Comment: mine does fail on it.  I explain that it fails in my answer and that Regexes alone aren't a complete solution here :)  I was looking at yours and got the initial impression it got around that problem because of the `^.*.*$` but it doesn't and I was pointing that out in case you didn't know.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry, I think I misinterpreted. I felt something was wrong with having lookbehind and lookahead together, but could find an example (I was lazy :).