# RegEx to exclude match string, but not if part of another string

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a follow up question to this post: [RegEx to exclude match if a certain word is present, but not another partial word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162921/regex-to-exclude-match-if-a-certain-word-is-present-but-not-another-partial-word) .

If given the following string.

```
x*vec*grad(vec)
```

How do I find 'vec' but not 'grad(vec)'?

I am assuming I will need to use something like the following for the search expression, but this doesn't work for me.

```
vec(?!(?<=grad\(vec))
```

I also want to ignore the space inside the parentheses, i.e. it should work for the following.

```
x*vec*grad( vec )
```

I am using MATLAB's regexp function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in c#, it should port to MATLAB easily enough:

```
(?<!grad\()vec
```

It matches `vec*grad` but not `x*grad(vec)`.

The trick is to use the negative lookbehind (`<!`) instead of tyring to invert the positive lookbehind (`<=`).

Comment: Adding the \s* accounts for whitespace. So, `(?<!grad\(\s*)vec` is doing what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it will break with `vec*somefunc(vec)`, or funky stuff like `vec*outerfunc(innerfunc(vec) * vec * factor, vec, somethingelse)`